# iPad not accepting session variable after login

Tags: php, session, authentication, safari

When a user attempts to login, the `form action` is in a sub folder named phpfunctions, at which point a `$_SESSION` variable is created with the username. I redirect the user from this page to another page held in the parent directory.
Initially i used

```
header('Location: ..\rota.php ');
```

however, safari did not like this, and returned an error reading;

The requested URL /phpfunctions/..\rota.php was not found on the server

I then used the whole URL address instead;

```
 header('Location: http://www.asktom.yourwebsolution.net/rota.php');
```

This does redirect the page. The problem is that to access the content on that page a `$_SESSION` variable must be true. This is not the case in this example and the page appears empty.

I `var_dumped` the session variable on the rota.php page and it returns `NULL`. This redirection methods works for me on all major browsers on PC and works fine on my windows phone. Safari is the only browser this doesn't work in. Am i missing something?

Comment: Maybe `../rota.php`? As far as I know, there's no guarantee that backslash will work for "folders" in URLs.

Comment: wow, that fixed it, is that the standard or is that just for safari?

Comment: Should work everywhere, although I've not looked `..` paths up in the actual standard.

Comment: also note its `$_SESSION` not `$SESSION`